# Matlab image filtering with vector coefficients

Tags: image, matlab, filter

I'm trying to create a filter that uses vectors as coefficients.

A typical kernel used in `imfilter` looks like:

```
0  1  0
1 -4  1
0  1  0
```

Where each element is a scalar, and the filtering basically takes all windows of 3x3 of the image (MxN), multiplies the pixel values by the matching coefficients and sums all products to place the output pixel.

I would like to extend this, so that each element in the kernel is not a scalar, but actually a vector (Px1).  This makes the kernel something like 3x3xP.  The rest of the functionality should be the same:  Multiply the coefficient (vector) by the image pixel (scalar * vector),   sum all products (sum of vectors of same dimensions), and the output matrix should have the dimensions of  (MxNxP).

I know that `imfilter` doesn't support that and produces a result of (MxN).

Is there another Matlab function that does this, or do I need to implement from scratch?

Some comments: The image is usually logical (0 or 1), and some of the filter elements can be zero, and not contribute to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Without another solution, I would brute-force it.  If each vector in your 3x3 filter has P elements, I'd apply each element independently and sum the result.

```
%load my image
im = imread(fname);

%define my kernel
h = zeros(3,3,P);  % P elements deep
h(:,:,1) = [0  1  0; 1 -4  1; 0  1  0];  %first element my kernel
h(:,:,2) = [0.2  1.5  0.2; 1.5 -6  1.5; 0.2  1.5  0.2]; %second element
%keep adding elements until you get your P elements

%loop over each element in your kernel
output = zeros(size(im))
for I=1:size(h,3)
    output = output + imfilter(im,h(:,:,I));  %apply filter and accumulate
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this code generates an output that is the same format as the image, and basically sums a series of regular filters.  I'm trying to generate an output in which each 'pixel' is a vector of size P, containing the sum of products of my filter vectors and the image pixels.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the problem better.  A similar problem to yours might be that you have P movie frames of size MxN.  You want to do a smoothing filter in both space (within one frame) and time (across frames).  That is indeed a different problem.  I don't know of a built-in function...only to do it via `for` loops